# WPF AutoCompleteBox DropDown Width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following AutoCompleteBox:

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="txtComponent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                TextSearch.TextPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                FontSize="13.333" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DropDownClosing="txtComponent_DropDownClosing">
    <Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SiteName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</Controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

The problem is that the suggestions drop down list is stretching out of the bound.

[image]

How can I set the max width of the DropDown list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5293508/2470362

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoCompleteBox Dropdown width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293297/autocompletebox-dropdown-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SiteName}" Width="{Binding ElementName=txtComponent, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

It should traverse the tree and bind the dropdown width to the parent width.

Comment: Where should I write it? In the TextBlock?